# variant of jq from_entries that collate values for each key occurrence

Tags: arrays, dictionary, key, grouping, jq

Can I use jq to run a filter that behaves similarly to from_entries, with the one difference being, if multiple entries for the same key are encountered, it will collate the values into an array, rather than just use the last value?

If so, what filter would achieve this? For example, if my input is:

```
[
  {
    "key": "a",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "key": "b",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "key": "a",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "key": "b",
    "value": 4
  }
]
```

then the desired output would be:

```
{ "a": [1,3], "b": [2,4] }
```

Note that, using 'from_entries' alone as the filter, the resulting values are just the last value (that is, `{ "a": 3, "b": 4 }`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jq: group and key by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221453/jq-group-and-key-by-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your example and the following lines in merge.jq:

```
def merge_entries:
  reduce .[] as $pair ({}; .[$pair["key"]] += [$pair["value"]] );

merge_entries
```

the invocation: jq -c -f merge.jq
yields:

```
{"a":[1,3],"b":[2,4]}
```

You could also use the invocation:

```
jq 'reduce .[] as $p ({}; .[$p.key] += [$p.value])'
```

Comment: Sorry for misreading the original question.  I was distracted by some aspects of the first paragraph. Even now it says "if multiple entries of the same key exist" without specifying what should be done if that is not the case.

Comment: No, you were right. I started writing it from one angle, then switched halfway through and didn't update the beginning to make it consistent. I've further narrowed and updated per your last comment, hopefully better now, feel free to lmk if not. Ty